# initialize dictionary values from another class

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a class names clsDictionary.....

```
public class ClsDictionary
{ 
    private Dictionary<string, string> Details;

    public  ClsDictionary()
    {
        Details = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    }

    public Dictionary<string, string> getDictionary()
    {
        return this.Details;
    }


}
```

Now i add to add values to details dictionary

that is i need to add all the input values from the form and in my webform i tried some thing like this

```
protected void btnPayment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

         Dictionary<string, string> Values = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        Values.Add("Email", txtEmail.Text);
        Values.Add("FirstName", txtFname.Text);
        Values.Add("LastName", txtLname.Text);
        Values.Add("Address1", txtAddress1.Text);
        Values.Add("Address2", txtAddress2.Text);
        Values.Add("City", txtCity.Text);
        Values.Add("State", txtState.Text);
        Values.Add("Country", txtCountry.Text);
        Values.Add("PinCode", txtPincode.Text);
        Values.Add("Phone", txtPhone.Text);
        Values.Add("Country", txtCountry.Text);

        ClsDictionary dict = new ClsDictionary();



    }
```

Now I neeed to assign Values  dictionary to details dictionary which is in another class

Comment: why are you not directly using dict.Details instead of Values?

Comment: individual value i mean i need to retrieve email value in a variable in another page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have your `ClsDictionary` class take it as a constructor argument:

```
public class ClsDictionary
{ 
    private Dictionary<string, string> Details;

    public ClsDictionary() 
        : this(new Dictionary<string, string>())
    {
    }

    public ClsDictionary(Dictionary<string, string> details)
    {
        this.Details = details;
    }

    public Dictionary<string, string> getDictionary()
    {
        return this.Details;
    }
}
```

and then:

```
ClsDictionary dict = new ClsDictionary(Values);
```

Alternatively you could have a method that will clear the original dictionary and replace it with the new values:

```
public void UpdateDetails(Dictionary<string, string> details)
{
    this.Details = new Dictionary<string, string>(details);
}
```

and then:

```
ClsDictionary dict = new ClsDictionary();
dict.UpdateDetails(Values);
```

Answer (score 1):

to add values to details dictionary

```
protected void btnPayment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClsDictionary dict = new ClsDictionary();
    Dictionary<string, string> Values = dict.getDictionary();
    Values.Add("Email", txtEmail.Text);
    Values.Add("FirstName", txtFname.Text);
    Values.Add("LastName", txtLname.Text);
    Values.Add("Address1", txtAddress1.Text);
    Values.Add("Address2", txtAddress2.Text);
    Values.Add("City", txtCity.Text);
    Values.Add("State", txtState.Text);
    Values.Add("Country", txtCountry.Text);
    Values.Add("PinCode", txtPincode.Text);
    Values.Add("Phone", txtPhone.Text);
    Values.Add("Country", txtCountry.Text);
}
```

you can also try this, if you can change ClsDictionary

```
public class ClsDictionary
{ 
    public  ClsDictionary()
    {
        Details = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    }

    public Dictionary<string, string> Details
    {
        get; private set;
    }
}

protected void btnPayment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClsDictionary dict = new ClsDictionary();
    Dictionary<string, string> Values = dict.Details;
    Values.Add("Email", txtEmail.Text);
    Values.Add("FirstName", txtFname.Text);
    Values.Add("LastName", txtLname.Text);
    Values.Add("Address1", txtAddress1.Text);
    Values.Add("Address2", txtAddress2.Text);
    Values.Add("City", txtCity.Text);
    Values.Add("State", txtState.Text);
    Values.Add("Country", txtCountry.Text);
    Values.Add("PinCode", txtPincode.Text);
    Values.Add("Phone", txtPhone.Text);
    Values.Add("Country", txtCountry.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use constructor which takes `Dictionary` as parameter or implement the `setDictionary` method or use ***public auto-implemented Property*** which creates a private, anonymous backing field that can only be accessed through the property's `get` and `set` accessors.

@Darin showed how to make first one, I am showing the last one:

Here is the syntax of auto-implemented Property:

```
public PropetyName{ get; set;}
```

If you want read-only or write-only property, then you can use:

```
 public PropetyName{ get; private set; } // Readonly in outside of the class implementation
 public PropetyName{ private get; set; } // Writeonly in outside of the class implementation
 public PropetyName{ get; } // Readonly
 public PropetyName{ set; } // Writeonly
```

So, you can change your code as:

```
public class ClsDictionary
{ 
    public Dictionary<string, string> Details { private get; set; }

    public  ClsDictionary()
    {
        Details = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    public  ClsDictionary(Dictionary<string, string> details)
    {
        Details = details;
    }
}
```

Then you can use:

```
ClsDictionary dict = new ClsDictionary();
dict.Details = Values;
```

or

```
ClsDictionary dict = new ClsDictionary(Values);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way:

```
public class ClsDictionary
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> Details;

    public ClsDictionary()
    {
        Details = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    }

    public Dictionary<string, string> getDictionary()
    {
        return this.Details;
    }

    public bool AddDetail(string name, string value)
    {
        if (this.Details.ContainsKey(name))
        {
            return false;
        }
        this.Details.Add(name, value);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then add with:

```
protected void btnPayment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClsDictionary dict = new ClsDictionary();
    dict.AddDetail("Email", txtEmail.Text);
    dict.AddDetail("FirstName", txtFname.Text);
    dict.AddDetail("LastName", txtLname.Text);
    dict.AddDetail("Address1", txtAddress1.Text);
    dict.AddDetail("Address2", txtAddress2.Text);
    dict.AddDetail("City", txtCity.Text);
    dict.AddDetail("State", txtState.Text);
    dict.AddDetail("Country", txtCountry.Text);
    dict.AddDetail("PinCode", txtPincode.Text);
    dict.AddDetail("Phone", txtPhone.Text);
    dict.AddDetail("Country", txtCountry.Text);

}
```

The AddDetail Method would return if the value is not added allready ... another way to implement is:

```
public void SetDetail(string name, string value)
{
    if (this.Details.ContainsKey(name))
    {
        this.Details[name] = value;
    }
    else
    {
        this.Details.Add(name, value);
    }
}
```

This would alter the Detail if its allready in the dictionary or add another value.